# SSRS Row Visibility

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am using the Switch function in Reporting Services to determine the visibility of a row. It happens that I am using more that one column or field to test my expression like so:

```
    =Switch(Parameters!View.Value = "Green" AND Fields!Tax.Value =    "N",TRUE,Parameters!View.Value = "Current" AND Fields!PastVal.Value = 0 AND Fields!DatePay.Value = 0 AND Fields!Comment.Value = 0,True)
```

With the expression above, I want that if the first part is true, the row should be hidden likewise for the second part of the expression, I want to hid a row when all the conditions are met. But this not yielding the desired result.

I equally tried with another expression like so:

```
    =IIF(Parameters!View.Value = "Green" AND Fields!Tax.Value = N",False, IIF(Parameters!View.Value = "Current" AND Fields!PastVal.Value = 0 AND Fields!DatePay.Value = 0 AND Fields!Comment.Value = 0,True,False))
```

That still did not work.

I anticipate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I  follow you correctly, I think putting both conditions in an IIF and separating them with an "OR" will work:

```
=IIF( (Parameters!View.Value = "Green" AND Fields!Tax.Value =    "N") OR (Parameters!View.Value = "Current" AND Fields!PastVal.Value = 0 AND Fields!DatePay.Value = 0 AND Fields!Comment.Value = 0) ),True,False)
```